# Getting error while creating RPM

Tags: rpm

I was trying to create customized apache rpm from spec file, but getting error like

```
[root@]# rpm -bb custom-apache.spec
-bb: unknown option
```

rpmbuild is also installed in my machine already

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke "rpmbuild -bb custom-apache.spec".

Make sure the rpm-build package is installed